# Why isn't append() appending the swapped list. It is appending original string but printing swapped list

Tags: python-3.x, string, permutation

nums: List whose permutations I need to find.
Leetcode problem: 46. 
I need to return a matrix containing all permutations of a list. When it reaches end of backtracking, I print nums and even append nums to matrix. It is printing swapped nums but it is appending original nums. Can some explain me the reason or how do I sought this problem out?

I tried creating v as a global matrix but it doesn't work.

```py
class Solution:
    def permutation(self, v, nums, l, r):
        if l == r-1:
            print(nums)
            v.append(nums)
        else:
            for i in range(l, r):
                nums[i], nums[l] = nums[l], nums[i]
                self.permutation(v, nums, l+1, r)
                nums[i], nums[l] = nums[l], nums[i]
            return v

    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        v = []
        return self.permutation(v, nums, 0, len(nums))
'''

Input:[1,2,3]
Printing:
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
Output:
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

Expected:
[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the same reference of the `nums` list to `v` every time. You should append a copy of the `nums` list instead.

Change:

```
v.append(nums)
```

to:

```
v.append(nums[:])
```